# No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config (not Kerberos)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-security

I'm trying to configure a kafka client to authenticate against a secure kafkaserver. I've set up the jaas and ssl configs, but it's complaining about serviceNames.

I am not using Kerberos.

**command**

```
KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./jaas.conf" \ 
kafka-console-producer --broker-list k0:9092,k1:9092,k2:9092 \
   --topic test-topic 
   --producer.config ./ssl.properties
```

**error**

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>
    [ ... ] 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
```

**jaas.conf**

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    serviceName="kafka"
    password="broker-secret"
    user_broker="broker-secret"
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
    confluent.metrics.reporter.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
    user_username1="password1";
};
```

**ssl.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=k0:9092,k1:9092,k2:9092
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
ssl.truststore.location=/var/ssl/private/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=confluent
ssl.keystore.location=/var/ssl/private/client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=confluent
ssl.key.password=confluent


producer.bootstrap.servers=k0:9092,1:9092,k2:9092
producer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
producer.ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.location=/var/ssl/private/client.truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.password=confluent
producer.ssl.keystore.location=/var/ssl/private/client.keystore.jks
producer.ssl.keystore.password=confluent
producer.ssl.key.password=confluent

org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
password="broker-secret"
user_broker="broker-secret"
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
confluent.metrics.reporter.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
user_username1="password";
serviceName="Kafka"
```

Comment: What is the content of `ssl.properties`?

Comment: ssl.properties -> ssl.conf (i had accidentally mis-named while sanitising it to copy it to this site)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error indicates that jaas configuration is not visible to your kafka producer. To solve this issue, you either need to include

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="(username)" password="(password)";
```

in your `ssl.properties` file, or export it in your path

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=path/to/jaas.conf"
```

Comment: still issue exist , any idea

Comment: I already have this config but the error `No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config` still happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and tried both options but did not worked. After searching all documents finally found that we have to give credentials like this

**If you are directly adding this into properties file then use this**

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="username" \
  password="password";
```

**If you are running kafka-connect, modify property file using echo command**

```
echo "sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \\
  username=\"${confluent_jass_config_username}\" \\
  password=\"${confluent_jass_config_password}\";" >> /opt/connector/config/connect-distributed.properties
```

- This approach is also useful when you have password with special character like + or forward slash, as in this cases jaas.conf file approach was not working for me but this worked and solved all errors
- Add same config property using producer or consumer prefix if its source or sink connectors