# Kafka 'no serviceName defined' issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, sasl

I have the same issue [No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config (not Kerberos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989683/no-servicename-defined-in-either-jaas-or-kafka-config-not-kerberos) but I can't solve it at all.

I'm trying to create org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient using properties when application startup:

```
public void init(@Observes @Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION) StartupEvent event) {
    log.info("Kafka startup event started!");
    
    Map<String, Object> properties = Map.of(
        "sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=user password=user;",
        AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "...",
        "sasl.jaas.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512",
        "security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT"
    );
    int partitions = 1;
    short replicationFactor = 1;

    NewTopic topic = new NewTopic("test-topic-name", partitions, replicationFactor);

    try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties)) {
        CreateTopicsResult result = adminClient.createTopics(
            Collections.singleton(topic)
        );
        KafkaFuture<Void> future = result.values().get(topic);

        future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And also have properties from application.yaml:

```
kafka:
 auto:
    create:
      topics:
        enable: false
  bootstrap:
    servers: {servers}
  sasl:
    jaas:
      config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=user password=user;
    mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-512
  security:
    protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

If I use only properties that's set from appl.yaml only - it's ok, but when I tried to use manually creation topic to clarify properties from MAP - had an issue.
I tried to specify serviceName from sasl.jaas.config like

```
org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=user password=user serviceName=Kafka;
```

But I still have an issue , but with authorization.
How can I create topic when startup only? Not using LAZY initialization. It's my main goal.

Used **quarkus**, **apache kafka**.

https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-topic-creation

Answer (score 4):

By refactoring the key
`"sasl.jaas.mechanism"`
to
`"sasl.mechanism"` it should work again.

Comment: Actually everyone who has this problem should check twice whether they don't have a typo in `sasl.mechanism` property. Most clients also accept `sasl.mechanisms` property but in case of e.g. kafka-console-consumer/producer scripts shipped with Kafka it has to be `sasl.mechanism`, not `sasl.mechanisms`... Personally, I lost few hours on this by copying SASL configuration from `kcat` to `kafka-console-consumer.sh`.

Comment: Try using this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/78115920/13898185