# No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config in KRaft Mode Kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kraft, bitnami-kafka

I am trying to use SASL_SSL for external clients, connecting to controller as an authentication mechanism, but its erring out.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: "2"

    services:
      kafka:
        image: bitnami/kafka:latest
        ports:
          - 9092:9092
          - 2181:2181
        volumes:
          - "kafka_data:/bitnami/kafka"
        environment:
          - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
          - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
          - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:SASL_SSL,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
          - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:2181
          - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
          - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
          - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-256,SCRAM-SHA-512
          - KAFKA_CLIENTS_USER=user
          - KAFKA_CLIENTS_PASSWORD=password
          - KAFKA_TLS_CLIENT_AUTH=none
          - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM=
          - KAFKA_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD=password
          - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
          - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@127.0.0.1:2181
          - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
        volumes:
          - './kafka.keystore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.keystore.jks:ro'
          - './kafka.truststore.jks:/opt/bitnami/kafka/config/certs/kafka.truststore.jks:ro'
          - './kafka_jaas.conf:/opt/bitnami/kafka/conf/kafka_jaas.conf:ro'

    volumes:
      kafka_data:
        driver: local
```

**kafka_jaas.conf**

```
    KafkaServer {
        org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
        username="kafka"
        password="password";
    };
```

**Error**

```
41-kafka-1  | [2022-12-05 21:28:08,493] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
41-kafka-1  | org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
```

[Full log with error](https://pastebin.com/Q3u9R1it)

I tried,

- [No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config (not Kerberos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989683/no-servicename-defined-in-either-jaas-or-kafka-config-not-kerberos)
- https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/issues/204

Comment: You mounted the file as a volume, but you're not adding it to the JVM arguments using `KAFKA_OPTS`?

Comment: Try using this way stackoverflow.com/a/78115920/13898185